# Is it possible to convert "UTF-16LE" to Unicode points using iconv?

Tags: c++, xml, unicode, utf-16, iconv

I need to validate the unicode char written to an XML file. All the characters written to XML file must conform to XML1.0 specs. Since XML1.0 lists the valid character set as unencoded unicode points and I have utf16 encoded characters.

How do I check whether a character conforms to XML1.0 specs?

[Valid character range in XML1.0 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)

Currently I m trying to  convert the utf16 to unicode points using iconv in c++. If not possible then I might have to manually convert it. Please suggest any elegant solution.

Thank you

Comment: Why not simply load the XML in an actual XML engine? There are plenty available to C++. Any one of them will decode the UTF-16 for you and validate the Unicode characters while parsing.  But, to answer your question, you can have iconv convert the UTF-16 data to UTF-32, that will give you the "unencoded" codepoints you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not know that UTF-32 is the "unencoded" codepoints. And we can not load the XML because we are creating the XML file, the UTF-16 characters are obtained from an OCR library. They are written to the XML file as bytes using `fwrite()`. Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: then why not validate the characters before you write them to file? And why are you writing the file manually instead of using an XML engine to write it? If you want conformance to the spec, use an engine that conforms to it

Comment: We have a valid reason for that. I cannot answer any of your questions due to confidential information. But thank you for the answer.